# How do I remove all but the "first" 3 characters in a cell in MS Excel 2010?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How do I remove all but the first 3 characters in a cell in Excel 2010? I have a column of data that I need to delete everything, which can be 6 more characters up to 30 more characters, except the first 3 characters. None of the characters are identical so Find & Replace won't work.

Answer (score 9):

Put this in B1 and copy it down. I am assuming that the data is in Col A.

```
=LEFT(A1,3)
```

Comment: Even you can become one ;) Press the magic key in Excel whenever in doubt. It's called `F1` :P